# Use curl to renew a JWT access token with CSRF protection enabled

Tags: curl, cookies, django-rest-framework, csrf

I'm using django rest framework with the simplejwt package, I plan to store my JWT token in a cookie and I'd like to use csrf protection for it.

Before writing the code in Django I'd like to check if everything works as intended so I'm using curl to try and get a new access token from the refresh endpoint provided by simplejwt (in form of default view and serializer which I'm using).

I'm using a csrf token value set according to a csrf token I obtain by requesting `'127.0.0.1:8000/admin/'`, but I get a 403 response stating the csrf authentication failed. This is my request:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer {refresh-token-value}" -b "csrftoken={csrf-token-value}" http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token_login/refresh/
```

I suspect I'm misunderstanding how csrf tokens are supposed to work but it might be that I'm using curl the wrong way. Can I obtain what I intend to get? How should I do it?

Comment: You wanna pass your CSRF Token as a header of request so use the same -H option to do that.
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token_login/refresh/ -H "Authorization: Bearer {refresh-token-value}" -H "X-CSRFToken: {csrf-token-value}"

Comment: I tried `curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/token_login/refresh/ -H "Authorization: Bearer {refresh-token-value}" -H "X-CSRFToken: {csrf-token-value}"`, the response is an html page stating that the endpoint requires a csrf cookie.

Comment: it turns out that (1) I made a mistake in the backend code that led to unexpected behavior including the csrf notice (2) the library expects the token to be sent as value of a json record (cutting out csrf in the first place as far as I understand).